# Cannot symlink database.yml through Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, symlink

Deployment fails after executing

```
run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
```

The error is:

```
`/var/apps/myserver.com/shared/config/database.yml' and `/var/apps/myserver.com/releases/20120925174051/config/database.yml' are the same file
```

Any idea? It seems to me that is is not a Capistrano issue but it happened just after I started to use rvm-capistrano gem.

Comment: The error seems to imply that the symlink already exists?

Comment: It can't  because it is a new deployment. /var/apps/myserver.com/releases/20120925174051/config/database.yml is a new directory.

Comment: Problem was that at some point of the deployment process a symlink of the config directory was created causing /var/apps/myserver.com/releases/20120925174051/config/ to point to /var/apps/myserver.com/shared/config/. Thank you anyways, your questions helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that at some point of the deployment a symlink of the config directory was created causing /var/apps/myserver.com/releases/20120925174051/config/ to point to /var/apps/myserver.com/shared/config/. Thank you anyways, your questions helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably added config to shared_children. Which means it'll remove the config directory in the release, and symlink it to the shared one instead.

The fix is of course to remove the config directory from shared_chilren in your deploy.rb.

*P.S. Yes, I know it's an old question, but it's the first hit on Google.*

Comment: Thanks. It was not specifically what you are saying but you were pretty close!